# Ember-cli server does not start, no error message

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm unsure why my ember does not start. When I type `ember server`, I see

```
PS C:\Users\lzc\Ember-Prototype> ember s
version: 0.2.3

A new version of ember-cli is available (0.2.7). To install it, type ember update.
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
PS C:\Users\lzc\Ember-Prototype>
```

I'm pretty sure its not the outdated CLI, because it was working very well for the pas week. When I type `ember build`, it instantly reads 'Building...` then finishes. Normally my builds are 60 to 80 seconds. I can't identify whether this is a compile issue or settings flaw. Shouldn't Ember-CLI give an error message if something went wrong like this?

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Did running 'ember server --verbose' provide any further info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't run `--verbose', no command in CLI. Issue was when liquid modal tried to register transitions, one of the path strings was incorrect. No error messages given.